# How to get the colour of a applet viewer pixel in Java?

Tags: java, graphics2d, japplet

I have drawn any picture, used Graphics 2D. How do I get the colour of a pixel at x, y? getPixelColor don't work, because this method get pixel from screen, not applet viewer coordinates.

Comment: r u using Applet class or JApplet class?

Comment: if not using Robot getPixelColor, i can only think of converting the applet graphics object to bitmap, then extract from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Draw the picture to the `Graphics` of a `BufferedImage`
2. Draw the image to the `Graphics2D`.
3. To get the color of any pixel, call [`BufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) or variants (check the docs.).